# image share issue for single variant product

Tags: commerce

I am using [Service Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/service_links) module. On product display page, one of the product variant is displayed. The products having more than 1 variant, sharing proper image [shows meta property="og:image" content="..." in view source ]. 
But single variant product is not producing og meta tag.

I am using token [node:field-product:1:field_images] in Images input field of 'Open Graph' meta tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 0 instead of 1 in node image token

1) Go to : Site setting -> configuration -> Metatag

2) Edit the “Node”

3) Click On Open Graph field set

4) Add “[node:field-product:0:field_images]” in Image

Hope this will solve your issue